# How to uninstall the GlobalProtect App from Macbook?

Tags: macos

Recently I have install GlobalProtect vpn on my Macbook and found it very difficult to uninstall it since it was opening on startup. Is there any specific way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen over the web that a lot of Apple Macbook users struggle with this, therefor I have decided to create a guide that shows two options on how to unistall the GLobalProtect App on macOS.

1. You need to download the initial GlobalProtect Installer, as you go through the steps shows an option for uninstall
2. Copy and paste the following code on the terminal window

> sudo
> /Applications/GlobalProtect.app/Contents/Resources/uninstall_gp.sh

You can find more [here](https://www.panayiotisgeorgiou.net/how-to-uninstall-the-globalprotect-app-from-macbook/)